# Why is the result of a reduction different for a sequential and a parallel stream?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream

I have the following list `integers` (all numbers from 0 to 999,999):

```
List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i != 10_000_000; ++i) {
    integers.add(i);
}
```

I'm trying to run the following as a Java 8 Stream:

```
int sum = 0;
for (Integer i : integers) {
    sum = i % 2 == 0 ? i - sum : i + sum;
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

I expect the following output:

```
0 - 0 = 0  
1 + 0 = 1  
2 - 1 = 1   
3 + 1 = 4  
4 - 4 = 0  
5 + 0 = 5  
6 - 5 = 1  
7 + 1 = 8
8 - 8 = 0   
...
999,998 - 999,997 = 1
999,999 + 1 = 10,000,000
```

`10,000,000`(btw, can someone maybe express this mathematically? I can't...)

If I run this:

```
int sum = integers.stream().reduce(
                0,
                (sum, i) -> i % 2 == 0 ? i - sum : i + sum
            );
```

`sum` is the expected amount, `10,000,000`.

However, if I change the stream to being parallel:

```
int sum = integers.parallelStream().reduce(
                0,
                (sum, i) -> i % 2 == 0 ? i - sum : i + sum
            );
```

`sum` is `0`!

I can't seem to figure out why this is the case, can someone explain this?

Comment: It would still be interesting to me **why** it's **always** 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Javadoc for `reduce`:

> Performs a reduction on the elements of this stream, using an associative accumulation function,

Note the word "associative": this is a property your reducing function does not possess.

Associativity is key to parallelization: the order of application of operations is not defined, and without associativity the result will not be invariant under reordering.

If you have more than two `availableProcessors`, you can play with the following code to convince yourself that the answer depends on the number of subtasks (note that you shouldn't use 10_000_000 as the problem size because it has to many two's in its factorization; use 10_000_001):

```
System.setProperty("java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism", "2");
System.out.println(IntStream.range(0,10_000_001).parallel().reduce(0,
    (sum, i) -> i % 2 == 0 ? i - sum : i + sum
));
```

As you change the value of the system property, the result also changes.